# refactor 3 lines of javascript to minimize code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to refactor the three lines of code in the else part of the conditional, you'll see where I have it commented.

You'll notice a naming convention for the id's: id, id-div, as seen in the first line: club-community-service, club-community-service-id

I want to shorten that up. I thought maybe storing all names into an array, then looping thru them like (below). If there is a better way to go about this, I am all ears, thanks!

```
//in theory
array names = [names...];

foreach(names as n) {
  $("#" + n + "-div").toggle($("#" + n).get(0).checked);
}

$('#high-school-student').bind('click', function() {

  if($("input[id=high-school-student]").is(":checked")) {

    $('.field.full.club-community-service, .field.full.other-campus-activities, .field.full.community-public-service, .field.full.other-community-event-activity, .field.honors-program, .field.full.out-of-hs-5-years').hide();

    $('#club-community-service-div, #other-campus-activities-div, #community-public-service-div, #other-community-event-activity-div').hide();

  } else {

    $('.field.full.club-community-service, .field.full.other-campus-activities, .field.full.community-public-service, .field.full.other-community-event-activity, .field.honors-program, .field.full.out-of-hs-5-years').show();

    // ------ RIGHT HERE - best way to refactor these next three lines
    $("#club-community-service-div").toggle($('#club-community-service').get(0).checked);
    $("#other-campus-activities-div").toggle($('#other-campus-activities').get(0).checked);
    $("#community-public-service-div").toggle($('#community-public-service').get(0).checked);
  }
});

$('.watch-for-toggle').bind('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $('#' + id + '-div').toggle();
});
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't figure out a way to shorten those three lines without being too tangled (without modifying the html), but I would rewrite your code in this way:

```
$('#high-school-student').bind('click', function() {

  var highSchoolStudent = $(this).is(":checked");
  $('.field.full.club-community-service, .field.full.other-campus-activities, .field.full.community-public-service, .field.full.other-community-event-activity, .field.honors-program, .field.full.out-of-hs-5-years').toggle(!highSchoolStudent);

  if (highSchoolStudent) { 

    $('#club-community-service-div, #other-campus-activities-div, #community-public-service-div, #other-community-event-activity-div').hide();

  } else {

     //Use a multiselector, convert the result to array and iterate over it.
     //I used replace to remove the '-div'. A regular expression would be a more elegant solution.
     $.each($('#club-community-service-div, #other-campus-activities-div, #community-public-service-div').toArray(), function(i,v) { 
        $(v).toggle($(v.id.replace('-div', '')).is(':checked'))
     });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

  }

});
```

Comment: You can do `$('#foo, #bar').each(function(elem() {});`, it's better and more concise.

Comment: @ANeves is right. You can use: 
`$('#club-community-service-div, #other-campus-activities-div, #community-public-service-div').each(function(i,elem) {$(elem).toggle(elem.id.replace('-div',''))});`

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the `div` tags and can make the html something like this:

```
<div id='club-community-service-div' data-rel='club-community-service' class='check-toggle'>
```

then you can do something like this:

```
$('.check-toggle').toggle(function () { return document.getElementById($(this).data('rel')).checked; });
```

However, a much better change to this code would be to cache the various DOM traversals.

Answer (score 1):

@BillBarry proposes a good way to address your problem.

### Other improvements

1. Write `$("input#high-school-student")` instead of `$("input[id=high-school-student]")`;
2. But in your particular use, write `$(this)`, since the element is the one raising the event;
3. Use JQuery 1.7's `.on()` instead of `.bind()`;
4. What if the checkbox changes without being clicked? You should bind to other events as well: `input` (mind IE!), `change`, etc.
5. You can use `.toggle(bool)` to show/hide the element list, instead of doing the if and repeating the selector;
6. You should **cache and re-use** the JQuery DOM elements, where possible, instead of repeatedly getting them (but avoid polluting the global scope);
7. Naming an id `foo-div` raises alarm bells, it's "hungarian notation" for HTML! Why aren't you just targeting `#foo > div` or `#foo div` instead?? Even if you have other divs in there, you can give it a class - `#foo > .bar`. Or if it's adjacent, `#foo + div`. Etc.;

5:

```
var isHighSchoolStudent = $(this).is(':checked');
$('.field.full.club-community-service, .field.full.other-campus-activities, .field.full.community-public-service, .field.full.other-community-event-activity, .field.honors-program, .field.full.out-of-hs-5-years'
    ).toggle(!isHighSchoolStudent);
```